# expired cookies in browser and frames

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

I have some doubts regarding cookies and frames in web pages . Consider the below scenario.

Say an application sets a cookie when a user successfully finishes his login .The application will show the url , only when the user goes with a cookie . User visits some page in application and I do a bookmark of a particular frame in that page. Now user logs out. The application makes the cookie as expired.

Now if I am launching the bookmarked url ( url of a frame in the previously visited page) , Will that cookie get passed to server ?

In short , when I do bookmark , will the cookie associated with that page , get cached in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Expired cookies should be deleted by the browser, since they're expired & deleted they won't cache with your bookmarks. You probably shouldn't just use cookies if this needs to be really secure because they're easy to hijack; also you should try to avoid using frames if possible (they're deprecated in html5, bad UX)...

Comment: so , when doing bookmark , the cookie will not get cached by browser right ?

Comment: It shouldn't because bookmarking is an action performed by the browser, and cookies is an action performed by the website itself, they're separate.